# Why is the animation attribute of CSS not working in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I try to dynamically bind the `animation` attribute of CSS in Vue.js in order to change the animation according to other variables. My implementation is like below:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div :style="{transform: getTrans(), animation: getAni()}">Test</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from "vue";
    export default {
      name: "Lottery",
      methods: {
        getTrans() {
          return "rotateX(120deg)";
        },
        getAni() {
          return "back-spin 5s linear 0s 1 normal none running;";
        }
      }
    };
</script>
```

But when I run the code, I cannot see `animation` attribute in the CSS style of `div`. And the animation doesn't start. Why is the `animation` attribute of CSS not working in Vue.js when I dynamically bind the value of it?

The full code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6k4vzngt/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Your animation parameter has an extra ';' between the quotation marks ""

```
return "back-spin 5s linear 0s 1 normal none running;";
```

Remove that extra ';' and the parameter should show up (See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Robb216/p7yk3do9/4/))

```
return "back-spin 5s linear 0s 1 normal none running";
```